# Why is my floating shelf falling forward?

Tags: mounting, shelving

Here's what the shelf looks like:

[image: back of the shelf showing the hanger brackets]

I tried putting two screws in the wall but when I hang it on keeps falling forward, like it's too top heavy...The screws are quite firmly in there but the shelf just falls forward and off.

Here is what one of the two screws looks like (fingers included for scale). I tried screwing them all the way into the wall but then the shelf just fell straight down.

[image: A screw in the wall]

Comment: take the screw off the wall and see if it fits properly into the keyway on back of shelf

Comment: See the accepted answer to the above question. All the info & more you'd ever want or need to know about installing something that hangs from a keyhole slot

Comment: The screw is not in enough. The head of the screw slides into the thin grove at the back of the shelf. The shelf will lean until it is being held by the screw heads. If you screw all the way in, then you cannot slide the shelf grove over the head so the shelf will just fall off. You have to screw in so that it is out just enough to allow the screw to slide tightly into the shelve grove. To far out, the shelf will lean, to far in the shelf will not mount. Try doing 1 turn increments,  then half-turn increments, until you get it to mount snug

Answer (score 1):

Is this the way you installed the shelf? Note the direction of the slot (large hole down), and you shall make sure that the screw head is large enough to engage the metals on the sides of the small hole once set in place.

[image]